# Drawing Wealth of Nations D3 graph using React

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot, nvd3.js

I want to draw the wealth of nations interactive graph visualization using React js in my App but im not sure how to proceed in d3 version 5.

This is what i want to make:

> https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/the-wealth-health-of-nations

I am not sure how to proceed with it and how to create a component out of it.

Any quick help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your link isn't working and your question needs more details. Where are you stuck exactly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you try this link https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/the-wealth-health-of-nations 
I have to get it to work in my react app. I dont know how to proceed with it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to work around it and have come up with a component that creates it. It might not be hundred percent done but it gets the chart with transition effect as well. The transition is not not that great but it does the work for me.
I have created two components for it. The first component is just a base component that renders the main chart(**BubbleScatter**) and also the year that can be scrolled to have the effect of the changes in bubbles at different years.

Parent Component -  **DateSelector**:

```
import React from "react";
import BubbleScatterPlot from "./InteractiveScatterPlot";

class DateSelector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      year: 1800,
      changeTime: false,
      textInput: ""
    };
  }

  enableChange = e => {
    this.setState({ changeTime: true });
  };

  disableChange = () => {
    this.setState({ changeTime: false });
  };

  // Update data on scrolling over date text
  scrollDate = (e, d) => {
    e.persist();
    const dateInterval = 1; // As data increases every 20 years
    const startDate = 1800;
    const endDate = 2008;
    const total_year_count =
      Math.ceil((endDate - startDate) / dateInterval) + 1; // 2008 - 1800 / 20
    const diff = this.state.textInput.offsetWidth / total_year_count;

    let { changeTime } = this.state;
    let currX = e.pageX - this.state.textInput.offsetLeft;
    let currentDate = startDate + dateInterval * Math.floor(currX / diff);
    if (changeTime && currentDate !== this.state.year) {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        year: Math.min(currentDate, 2008) // Set the date
      }));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="WealthOfNations">
        <BubbleScatterPlot
          height={this.props.height}
          width={this.props.width}
          margin={this.props.margin}
          year={this.state.year}
        />
        <span
          ref={textInput => {
            this.state.textInput = textInput;
          }}
          onMouseEnter={this.enableChange}
          onMouseMove={this.scrollDate}
          onMouseLeave={this.disableChange}
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            width: "fit-content",
            color: "#9e9e9e63",
            background: "#e8e8e842",
            textAlign: "center",
            cursor: "ew-resize",
            fontSize: "6em",
            marginLeft: "80%"
          }}
        >
          {`${this.state.year}`}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DateSelector;
```

The actual BubbleScatterPlot

```
import { max as d3Max, extent as d3ArrayExtent } from "d3-array";
import React from "react";
import { scaleLinear, scaleLog } from "d3-scale";
import {
  axisBottom as d3AxisBottom,
  axisRight as d3AxisRight,
  axisTop as d3AxisTop,
  axisLeft as d3AxisLeft
} from "d3-axis";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { select as d3Select } from "d3-selection";
import Data from "./nations.json"; // External file containing data
import { Motion, spring } from "react-motion";
import { interpolateValues } from "./Interpolate";

const calculateRange = (data, subFieldName) => {
  let min, max;
  data.forEach(item => {
    let currentRange = d3ArrayExtent(item[subFieldName], item => {
      return item[1];
    });
    if (min === undefined || currentRange[0] < min) min = currentRange[0];
    if (max === undefined || currentRange[1] > max) max = currentRange[1];
  });
  if (min === 0) return [1, max];
  return [min, max];
};

//Helper function to extract value corresponding to year for every country item
const getYearData = (data, subFieldName, year) => {
  let result = data[subFieldName].find(values => {
    return values[0] == year;
  });
  return result ? result[1] : interpolateValues(data, subFieldName, year);
};

//Helper function to calculate radius
const calcRadius = value => {
  return Math.sqrt(value);
};

// Main component
const BubbleScatterPlot = props => {
  let xScale = scaleLog()
    .domain(calculateRange(Data, "income"))
    .range([0, props.width * 1.1]);
  let yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain(calculateRange(Data, "lifeExpectancy"))
    .range([props.height * 1.1, 0])
    .clamp(true);

  // Radius scale calculations based on population field
  let rRange = calculateRange(Data, "population");
  let rScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([calcRadius(rRange[0]), calcRadius(rRange[1])])
    .range([0, 80]);
  let color = d3
    .scaleOrdinal(
      Data.map(d => d.region),
      d3.schemeCategory10
    )
    .unknown("black");

  return (
    <svg
      width={props.width + props.margin}
      height={props.height + props.margin}
      margin={props.margin}
      style={{ overflow: "visible" }}
    >
      <g
        className="margins"
        style={{ transform: `translate(${props.margin}px, ${props.margin}px)` }}
      >
        <Axis
          h="x-bottom"
          {...props}
          data={Data}
          Scale={xScale}
          translateY={yScale(0)}
        />
        <Axis h="y-left" {...props} data={Data} Scale={yScale} />
        <g className="scatter">
          {Data.map(circlePoint => (
            <Motion
              style={{
                // Get income and scale it for x-axis for all items for 2006
                x: spring(getYearData(circlePoint, "income", props.year), {
                  stiffness: 200,
                  damping: 50
                }),
                // Get lifeExpectancy and scale it for y-axis for all items for 2006
                y: spring(
                  getYearData(circlePoint, "lifeExpectancy", props.year),
                  {
                    stiffness: 200,
                    damping: 50
                  }
                ),
                // Get radius and scale it for x-axis for all items for 2006
                r: spring(getYearData(circlePoint, "population", props.year), {
                  stiffness: 150,
                  damping: 50
                })
              }}
              key={`${circlePoint.name}`}
            >
              {({ x, y, r }) =>
                // Due to nature of log Scale !== 1, we dont render these items
                (x !== 1 || y !== 1) && (
                  <circle
                    cx={xScale(x)}
                    cy={yScale(y)}
                    r={rScale(calcRadius(r))}
                    fill={color(circlePoint.region)}
                    style={{ opacity: "0.7" }}
                  />
                )
              }
            </Motion>
          ))}
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

// Basic Axis unit
const AxisUnit = props => {
  let axis = props
    .orientation()
    .scale(props.Scale)
    .ticks(props.numberOfTicks || props.data.length / 2)
    .tickFormat(item => {
      return item;
    });

  return (
    <g
      className={"Axis "}
      ref={node => d3Select(node).call(axis)}
      style={{
        transform: `translate(${props.translateX || 0}px,${props.translateY ||
          0}px)`
      }}
    />
  );
};

const xAxis = "x",
  yAxis = "y",
  bottom = "bottom",
  top = "top",
  left = "left",
  right = "right";

const Axes = function axisHOC(WrapperComponent) {
  return class AxisHOC extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    getOrientation = () => {
      switch (this.props.h) {
        case xAxis + "-" + bottom:
          return {
            orientation: d3AxisBottom,
            className: xAxis + "-" + bottom,
            translateY: this.props.translateY || this.props.height
          };
        case yAxis + "-" + left:
          return {
            orientation: d3AxisLeft,
            className: yAxis + "-" + left,
            transform: -90
          };
        case xAxis + "-" + top:
          return {
            orientation: d3AxisTop,
            className: xAxis + "-" + top,
            translateY: this.props.translateY || this.props.height
          };
        case yAxis + "-" + right:
          return {
            orientation: d3AxisRight,
            className: yAxis + "-" + right,
            transform: 90
          };
        default:
          return { orientation: d3AxisLeft, className: yAxis + "-" + left };
      }
    };

    render() {
      const newProps = this.getOrientation();
      return <WrapperComponent {...this.props} {...newProps} />;
    }
  };
};

const Axis = Axes(AxisUnit);

export default BubbleScatterPlot;
```

Apart from this to have a smooth transition and interpolate missing numbers add this interpolation function as well:

```
import _ from "lodash";

export const interpolateValues = (data, subFieldName, year) => {
  // Get value of the last available year
  let prevVal = _.findLast(data[subFieldName], item => item[0] < year);
  // Get value of next available year
  let nextVal = data[subFieldName].find(item => item[0] > year);
  // Interpolation
  if (!prevVal && !nextVal) {
    return 1;
  } //In case country field is empty
  else if (!prevVal) {
    return nextVal[1];
  } //In case there is no available prior date
  else if (!nextVal) {
    return prevVal[1];
  } //In case there is no available next date
  else {
    let totalSteps = nextVal[0] - prevVal[0];
    let yearDistance = year - prevVal[0];
    //Linear interpolation
    return prevVal[1] + ((nextVal[1] - prevVal[1]) / totalSteps) * yearDistance;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works for me :)
The animation is not so smooth as you had correctly mentioned but it solves my problem.